# Sort rows grouped by grep alphabetically

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a row full of adverse events but also relationships of these adverse events to the procedure, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  adverse_event = c(
    "Haemorrhage", "related", "likely related",
    "Other", "related", "likely related", "Pain", "related", "likely related",
    "Subcapsular hematoma", "related", "likely related", "Ascites",
    "related", "likely related", "Hyperbilirubinemia", "related",
    "likely related", "Liver abscess", "related", "likely related",
    "Pleural effusion with drainage", "related", "likely related",
    "Pneumothorax", "related", "likely related", "Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula",
    "related", "likely related", "Portal vein thrombosis", "related",
    "likely related", "Sepsis", "related", "likely related"
  ),
  grade_1 = c(
    4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  grade_2 = c(
    2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  grade_3 = c(
    1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L,
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
  ),
  grade_4 = c(
    2L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  )
)
```

Now I'd like to sort the adverse events alphabetically but of course take the "related", "likely related" rows with the individual adverse event rows, so I'd like to somehow group them first.
In this example it's always 3 rows, but let's assume it could be sometimes 2, 4 or 5 rows too (all except the adverse event rows containing "related" in the string/name though e.g. 'unlikely related').

I know, I can get the indices of the adverse event rows by
`grep('related', df$adverse_event, invert = T)` but I'm unsure how to use this to group the rows together before sorting them.

Edit: Beginning of the left column of the desired output:

```
expected_output_left_column <- data.frame(adverse_event = c( 
"Ascites", "related", "likely related", 
"Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula", "related", "likely related" ) )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Comment: As I described I want to alphabetically sort but take the rows beneath the adverse events with them:
expected_output_left_column <- data.frame(
  adverse_event = c(
    "Ascites", "related", "likely related",
    "Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula", "related", "likely related"
  )
)

Comment: @d-math best to edit your question and provide sample data that explicitly shows your expected output, not in comments

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using base r and `lead` function from dplyr

```
# where start each group
id <- grep('related', df$adverse_event, invert = T)

# size of each group
size <- lead(id) - id
size_of_last_group <- nrow(df) - id[length(id)] + 1 
size[length(size)] <- size_of_last_group

# add col with id
df$id <- paste0(rep(df$adverse_event[id], times = size),
                df$adverse_event)

# order
df <- df[order(df$id), ]

# remove id
df$id <- NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  df, 
  df %>% 
    filter(!grepl('related',adverse_event)) %>% 
    select(adverse_event) %>% 
    arrange(adverse_event) %>% 
    mutate(o = row_number())
  ) %>% 
  mutate(o = data.table::nafill(o, "locf")) %>% 
  arrange(o) %>% 
  select(-o)
```

Output:

```
                           adverse_event grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4
1                                Ascites      NA       1      NA      NA
2                                related      NA       1      NA      NA
3                         likely related      NA       0      NA      NA
4  Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula      NA      NA       1      NA
5                                related      NA      NA       2      NA
6                         likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
7                            Haemorrhage       4       2       1       2
8                                related       4       3       4       4
9                         likely related       0       0       1       1
10                    Hyperbilirubinemia      NA       1      NA      NA
11                               related      NA       0      NA      NA
12                        likely related      NA       2      NA      NA
13                         Liver abscess      NA       1       4      NA
14                               related      NA       1       5      NA
15                        likely related      NA       0       1      NA
16                                 Other       3      11       5      NA
17                               related       6       3       3      NA
18                        likely related       1       7       2      NA
19                                  Pain       8       2       2      NA
20                               related       4       4       5      NA
21                        likely related       5       2       1      NA
22        Pleural effusion with drainage      NA       1      NA      NA
23                               related      NA       2      NA      NA
24                        likely related      NA       1      NA      NA
25                          Pneumothorax      NA       1       1      NA
26                               related      NA       1       1      NA
27                        likely related      NA       0       0      NA
28                Portal vein thrombosis      NA      NA       1      NA
29                               related      NA      NA       1      NA
30                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
31                                Sepsis      NA      NA       1      NA
32                               related      NA      NA       1      NA
33                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
34                  Subcapsular hematoma       3       1      NA      NA
35                               related       1       2      NA      NA
36                        likely related       3       0      NA      NA
```

Note that this uses `data.table::nafill()`.. A full `data.table` solution is as below:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

data.table(adverse_event =  sort(df[!grepl('related',adverse_event), adverse_event]))[, o:=.I][
  df, on="adverse_event"][, o:=nafill(o, "locf")][order(o), !c("o")]
```

Comment: You could also use `tidyr::fill` to stay within the tidyverse.

Comment: My favourite solution -  not the shortest but the most elegant and easiest to understand. 
Didn't know the na.fill in combination with 'locf'.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Be aware though, that in case of duplicated `adverse_events` this approach will break, try with `df <- df[rep(1:3, 2), ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "group" variable and sort

```
tmp=!grepl("related",df$adverse_event)
df$grp=cumsum(tmp)
df[order(match(df$grp,order(df$adverse_event[tmp]))),]

                           adverse_event grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4 grp
13                               Ascites      NA       1      NA      NA   5
14                               related      NA       1      NA      NA   5
15                        likely related      NA       0      NA      NA   5
28 Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula      NA      NA       1      NA  10
29                               related      NA      NA       2      NA  10
30                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA  10
1                            Haemorrhage       4       2       1       2   1
2                                related       4       3       4       4   1
3                         likely related       0       0       1       1   1
16                    Hyperbilirubinemia      NA       1      NA      NA   6
17                               related      NA       0      NA      NA   6
18                        likely related      NA       2      NA      NA   6
19                         Liver abscess      NA       1       4      NA   7
20                               related      NA       1       5      NA   7
21                        likely related      NA       0       1      NA   7
4                                  Other       3      11       5      NA   2
5                                related       6       3       3      NA   2
6                         likely related       1       7       2      NA   2
7                                   Pain       8       2       2      NA   3
8                                related       4       4       5      NA   3
9                         likely related       5       2       1      NA   3
22        Pleural effusion with drainage      NA       1      NA      NA   8
23                               related      NA       2      NA      NA   8
24                        likely related      NA       1      NA      NA   8
25                          Pneumothorax      NA       1       1      NA   9
26                               related      NA       1       1      NA   9
27                        likely related      NA       0       0      NA   9
31                Portal vein thrombosis      NA      NA       1      NA  11
32                               related      NA      NA       1      NA  11
33                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA  11
34                                Sepsis      NA      NA       1      NA  12
35                               related      NA      NA       1      NA  12
36                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA  12
10                  Subcapsular hematoma       3       1      NA      NA   4
11                               related       1       2      NA      NA   4
12                        likely related       3       0      NA      NA   4
```

Comment: This does not sort `adverse_event` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in another `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = if_else(grepl("related", adverse_event), 
                       NA_character_,
                       adverse_event)) %>% 
  fill(grp) %>% 
  nest(data = -grp) %>% 
  arrange(grp) %>% 
  unnest(cols = data) %>% 
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 36 × 5
#    adverse_event                         grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4
#    <chr>                                   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#  1 Ascites                                    NA       1      NA      NA
#  2 related                                    NA       1      NA      NA
#  3 likely related                             NA       0      NA      NA
#  4 Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula      NA      NA       1      NA
#  5 related                                    NA      NA       2      NA
#  6 likely related                             NA      NA       0      NA
#  7 Haemorrhage                                 4       2       1       2
#  8 related                                     4       3       4       4
#  9 likely related                              0       0       1       1
# 10 Hyperbilirubinemia                         NA       1      NA      NA
# 11 related                                    NA       0      NA      NA
# 12 likely related                             NA       2      NA      NA
# 13 Liver abscess                              NA       1       4      NA
# 14 related                                    NA       1       5      NA
# 15 likely related                             NA       0       1      NA
# 16 Other                                       3      11       5      NA
# 17 related                                     6       3       3      NA
# 18 likely related                              1       7       2      NA
# 19 Pain                                        8       2       2      NA
# 20 related                                     4       4       5      NA
# 21 likely related                              5       2       1      NA
# 22 Pleural effusion with drainage             NA       1      NA      NA
# 23 related                                    NA       2      NA      NA
# 24 likely related                             NA       1      NA      NA
# 25 Pneumothorax                               NA       1       1      NA
# 26 related                                    NA       1       1      NA
# 27 likely related                             NA       0       0      NA
# 28 Portal vein thrombosis                     NA      NA       1      NA
# 29 related                                    NA      NA       1      NA
# 30 likely related                             NA      NA       0      NA
# 31 Sepsis                                     NA      NA       1      NA
# 32 related                                    NA      NA       1      NA
# 33 likely related                             NA      NA       0      NA
# 34 Subcapsular hematoma                        3       1      NA      NA
# 35 related                                     1       2      NA      NA
# 36 likely related                              3       0      NA      NA
```

### Explanation

1. `mutate + fill`: Label each `adverse_event` with the stem, i.e. re-label all `related` records with the corresponding event above.
2. Nest all columns, but keep the newly created `grp` column, which bears the name of the stem adverse event.
3. Sort the adverse event stems.
4. Unnest the rows again.
5. Remove the `grp` column.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `rank`. Using an extended data set with 4 entries for "Ascites".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ord = !grepl("related", adverse_event), 
         grp = cumsum(ord), 
         Rank = rank(adverse_event[ord])[grp]) %>%   
  arrange(Rank) %>% 
  select(-c(ord, grp, Rank))
                           adverse_event grade_1 grade_2 grade_3 grade_4
1                                Ascites      NA       1      NA      NA
2                                related      NA       1      NA      NA
3                                related      NA       1      NA      NA
4                         likely related      NA       0      NA      NA
5  Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula      NA      NA       1      NA
6                                related      NA      NA       2      NA
7                         likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
8                            Haemorrhage       4       2       1       2
9                                related       4       3       4       4
10                        likely related       0       0       1       1
11                    Hyperbilirubinemia      NA       1      NA      NA
12                               related      NA       0      NA      NA
13                        likely related      NA       2      NA      NA
14                         Liver abscess      NA       1       4      NA
15                               related      NA       1       5      NA
16                        likely related      NA       0       1      NA
17                                 Other       3      11       5      NA
18                               related       6       3       3      NA
19                        likely related       1       7       2      NA
20                                  Pain       8       2       2      NA
21                               related       4       4       5      NA
22                        likely related       5       2       1      NA
23        Pleural effusion with drainage      NA       1      NA      NA
24                               related      NA       2      NA      NA
25                        likely related      NA       1      NA      NA
26                          Pneumothorax      NA       1       1      NA
27                               related      NA       1       1      NA
28                        likely related      NA       0       0      NA
29                Portal vein thrombosis      NA      NA       1      NA
30                               related      NA      NA       1      NA
31                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
32                                Sepsis      NA      NA       1      NA
33                               related      NA      NA       1      NA
34                        likely related      NA      NA       0      NA
35                  Subcapsular hematoma       3       1      NA      NA
36                               related       1       2      NA      NA
37                        likely related       3       0      NA      NA
```

##### extended data

```
df <- structure(list(adverse_event = c("Haemorrhage", "related", "likely related", 
"Other", "related", "likely related", "Pain", "related", "likely related", 
"Subcapsular hematoma", "related", "likely related", "Ascites", 
"related", "related", "likely related", "Hyperbilirubinemia", 
"related", "likely related", "Liver abscess", "related", "likely related", 
"Pleural effusion with drainage", "related", "likely related", 
"Pneumothorax", "related", "likely related", "Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula", 
"related", "likely related", "Portal vein thrombosis", "related", 
"likely related", "Sepsis", "related", "likely related"), grade_1 = c(4L, 
4L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), grade_2 = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), grade_3 = c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), grade_4 = c(2L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a benchmark of the different suggestions if needed :

```
library(bench)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
   adverse_event = c(
      "Haemorrhage", "related", "likely related",
      "Other", "related", "likely related", "Pain", "related", "likely related",
      "Subcapsular hematoma", "related", "likely related", "Ascites",
      "related", "likely related", "Hyperbilirubinemia", "related",
      "likely related", "Liver abscess", "related", "likely related",
      "Pleural effusion with drainage", "related", "likely related",
      "Pneumothorax", "related", "likely related", "Biliary leakage / occlusion / fistula",
      "related", "likely related", "Portal vein thrombosis", "related",
      "likely related", "Sepsis", "related", "likely related"
   ),
   grade_1 = c(
      4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
   ),
   grade_2 = c(
      2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
      1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
   ),
   grade_3 = c(
      1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L,
      1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
   ),
   grade_4 = c(
      2L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
   )
)

paul_carteron <- function(df){
   
   # where start each group
   id <- grep('related', df$adverse_event, invert = T)
   
   # size of each group
   size <- lead(id) - id
   size_of_last_group <- nrow(df) - id[length(id)] + 1 
   size[length(size)] <- size_of_last_group
   
   # add col with id
   df$id <- paste0(rep(df$adverse_event[id], times = size),
                   df$adverse_event)
   
   # order
   df <- df[order(df$id), ]
   
   # remove id
   df$id <- NULL
   
}

lang_tang_dplyr <- function(df){
   left_join(
      df,
      df %>%
         filter(!grepl('related', adverse_event)) %>%
         select(adverse_event) %>%
         arrange(adverse_event) %>%
         mutate(o = row_number())
   ) %>%
      mutate(o = data.table::nafill(o, "locf")) %>%
      arrange(o) %>%
      select(-o)
}

lang_tang_databable <- function(df) {
   setDT(df)
   
   data.table(adverse_event =  sort(df[!grepl('related',adverse_event), adverse_event]))[, o:=.I][
      df, on="adverse_event"][, o:=nafill(o, "locf")][order(o), !c("o")]
}

andre_wilberg <- function(df){
   df %>% 
      mutate(ord = !grepl("related", adverse_event), 
             grp = cumsum(ord), 
             Rank = rank(adverse_event[ord])[grp]) %>%   
      arrange(Rank) %>% 
      select(-c(ord, grp, Rank))
}

thotal <- function(df){
   df %>% 
      mutate(grp = if_else(grepl("related", adverse_event), 
                           NA_character_,
                           adverse_event)) %>% 
      fill(grp) %>% 
      nest(data = -grp) %>% 
      arrange(grp) %>% 
      unnest(cols = data) %>% 
      select(-grp)
}

results = bench::mark(
   iterations = 1000, check = FALSE, time_unit = "s", filter_gc = FALSE,
   paul_carteron = paul_carteron(df),
   lang_tang_dplyr = lang_tang_dplyr(df),
   lang_tang_databable = lang_tang_databable(df),
   andre_wilberg = andre_wilberg(df),
   thotal = thotal(df)
)

plot(results)
```

[image]